# Ripple effect does not work when the flutter widget is wrapped by Dismissible

Tags: flutter

I think the title is pretty clear!
Any widget I try to wrap with Dismissible will not be having any ripple effect when I click on it. But if I exclude Dismissible then it is fine!
How can I keep the Dismissible but have the ripple effect?